# How to transform between two ellipsoid representations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, positive-definite, ellipsoids

Claim:

$\mathcal{E}(x_c, 1) = \{x|(x - x_c)^T P^{-1} (x-x_c) \leq 1\}, P \in S^n_{++}$

has an alternative representation as:

$\mathcal{E}(x_c, 1) = \{x|\|Ax+b\|^2 \leq 1\}, A \in S^n_{++}$

---

What is a way to show this starting from

$\mathcal{E}(x_c, 1) = \{x|\|Ax+b\|^2 \leq 1\}, A \in S^n_{++}$?

Attempt:

the constraint is rewritten as:

$x^TA^TAx + 2b^TAx + b^Tb \leq 1$

Let $P^{-1} = A^TA, x_c = b$

Then we have $x^TP^{-1}x + 2b^TAx + x_c^Tx_c$

How should you proceed from here to get into $(x - x_c)^T P^{-1} (x-x_c)$  and how to deal with term in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A x^* = -b$, then the alternative representation is
$\|A(x-x^*)\|^2 \le 1$. That is,
$(x-x^*)^T A^TA (x-x^*) \le 1$.

From this we see that we have equivalence when $P^{-1} = A^T A$ and $x_c = x^*$.

Comment: Thanks do you know if there is a complete the square type of method that works for quadratic form of the type provided above?

Comment: Well, there must be.